# How to generate an ICO file from an SVG using maven?

Tags: maven-2, svg, rendering, ico

In my project I need an icon file (.ICO) for the Windows executable. I'd like to generate that file from an SVG, so it contains several images for different sizes. Is there a maven plugin that can do that for me?

I know I can just put an icon file in my repository, but the source file is an SVG image, so I'd like to avoid that.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is some Maven plugin for that. And also the problem goes a bit beyond maven itself.

What you can do is:

1. Transform SVG to PNG using [Apache Batik Rasterizer](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/tools/rasterizer.html)
2. Transform PNG to ICO using [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) and [JMagick](http://www.jmagick.org/index.html) wrapper
3. Create [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) script that will call 1 and 2, and add it to one of the maven lifesycle phases using [AntRun](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) plugin.

Comment: In the ImageMagick documentation, I can't find the option to create .ico files. And I want to have multiple images in one .ico file. Can you point me to that documentation?

Comment: Try using adjoin option: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#adjoin

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm sorry to say that the JMagick documentation is too sparse to work with. The Javadoc is not helpful at all, and the examples are incomplete. The same goes for the wiki.

Comment: I didn't accept it as The Correct Answer yet, since based on your description I still have to work out a lot of details myself, and didn't have the opportunity to do so. Furthermore, I still hope for a better answer :-)

Comment: Imagemagick is your best bet, it can convert nearly everything, for documentation look for the generic C examples, the java api is nearly identical

Comment: From a different source I got the suggestion to have a look at image4j.sourceforge.net. That looks promising.

Answer (score 2):

I came across your question looking for a solution to a very similar problem.  None of the answers given really suited me as I didn't want to get tied into running executables, so I wrote a pure Java Ant task (using Batik and image4j under the covers)

I've open sourced it at http://svg2ico.sourceforge.net/ - maybe you could call it from Maven?

Answer (score 1):

You can rasterize an SVG to a PNG on a web page by using [Google's canvg](http://code.google.com/p/canvg/) to push it into a Canvas, and then using `toDataURL()` on the canvas to get base64-encoded PNG data. You'd then need to decode that.

Or, you could use any number of server-side [SVG-to-PNG converters](http://www.google.com/search?q=svg+to+png).

*Not a better answer than @Andrey's, but showing more options for the first step.*

Answer (score 1):

The [batik-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/batik-maven-plugin/) will at least let you generate a PNG from SVG. Not sure how to generate the ICO, though.

Comment: Not possible within `batik-maven-plugin` - yet, suggested feature at https://github.com/trajano/batik-maven-plugin/issues/2